# Род слова «сундучишечко»

Tags: грамматика, род

*Малый сундучишечко* — какой род у слова "сундучишечко"? Средний или мужской?

Comment: наверное, мужской, сундук же, сундуков женского и среднего рода не встречал, только мужиков.

Comment: средний это малое сундучишечко, вполне допустимая формулировка. Существуют слова, так называемые асексуалы. Какой род захотим, такой и будет

Comment: Именно малый, а не малое. Поставили с ребенком мужской. Учитель зачеркнула. Почему средний, если малый?

Comment: Так вы у учителя спросите, видела ли она где-нибудь: малый мыло, малый гнездо, малый дупло

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сундучишко

Comment: Ольга, конечно, мужской, Вы правы. Уменьшительно-ласкательные суффиксы не меняют род слова. Мы же, например, не скажем "деревянное домишко (домище)", так же и с сундучищем, сундучишечкой.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что словечко "сундучишечко" было использовано в этом детском стихотворении:

*Под кустом сидит лягушечка,

Ровно каменна игрушечка,

Ровно **малый сундучишечко** —

Кверху вскинутая крышечка.*

> Детская литература не зря содержит достаточное количество слов с уменьшительно-ласкательными суффиксами. Авторы развивают эмоциональный интеллект детей, учат их вежливости, развивают умение проявлять свою любовь, преодолевать страх, видеть красоту и доброту мира.

"Сундучишечко" — это, конечно же, слово мужского рода. Об этом говорит и прилагательное "малый", к нему относящееся.
А уменьшительно-ласкательные суффиксы и впрямь не меняют род слова:
дом (м. р.) → домишко → домишечко, сундук (м. р.) → сундучишко → сундучишечко;
лягушка (ж. р.) → лягушечка, игрушка (ж. р.) → игрушечка,  подушка (ж. р.) → подушечка;
окно (с. р.) → окошко → окошечко, пальто (с. р.) → пальтишко → пальтишечко.

***Домишечко** был дряхл, уже двести лет назад он был глубоким старичком. Потом его подлатали* (Н. Соротокина. С видом на Париж, или Попытка детектива).

*А ну-ка, Игнас, снимай свой балахончик и надень это зимнее **пальтишечко** с блестящими пуговками!* (Григорий Канович. Очарованье сатаны).

[Новелла Матвеева. Страна Дельфиния](https://books.google.ee/books?id=YivKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT15&lpg=PT15&dq=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=rCpsks-CSN&sig=ACfU3U0rWHAj_SuwGLNOMhmc5skECcHmXw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXjPqAyK79AhVFxosKHbagBsw4ChDoAXoECBMQAw#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE&f=false)

Comment: Разве вводные слова отменяют тире перед "это"? По интонации — нет. В справочниках нет такого, потому что это неудачно (какая-то ломанная конструкция). После "это" ставят.

Comment: Да, сумлевалася я... И именно в этом месте. *Примечание. Обычно тире не ставится: <...> 4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово... Дубава, кажется, друг Корчагина (Н. О)...* (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91) Каюсь, бес попутал. "Щаз" поправлю, глазастый вы наш.