# Слова мужского рода, оканчивающиеся на -о

Tags: окончания, род

Из [Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm) известно, что слова **домишко и заборишко** имели ранее пары **домишка и заборишка**:

> Слова **домишко, заборишко** (мужского рода) и т.п. склоняются по типу
> имен существительных мужского-среднего рода: домишко, домишка,
> домишку, домишко, домишком, о домишке. Формы косвенных падежей
> домишки, домишке, домишку, домишкой являются разговорными и восходят к
> начальной форме **домишка** (ср. у Некрасова: Артикул ружьем выкидывал,
> так что весь **домишка** вздрагивал).

1. Нужен список всех слов мужского рода, оканчивающихся на -о
2. Почему эти слова изменили свои окончания, ведь это не логично?

Comment: Почему не логично?

Comment: Ну возьмите любое слово. Вор - воришка. Трус - трусишка. итд.

Comment: Интересно. Аа, здесь о человеке, поэтому форма среднего рода не подходит. А в других случаях такие слова тянет к форме среднего рода.

Comment: Ну да, дело даже не в одушевленности. Сравните "я приобрёл старенький колёсный тракторишко" и "Но почему-то какой-нибудь тракторишка". Какая из фраз верная? Обе? "Футболистишко из него так себе", а вот здесь одушевленность, но с -о.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/тракторишко В Гугл больше примеров с "футболистишка". Не надо такие слова образовывать. Удачны те, что обрели популярность и есть в словарях.

Comment: Что значит не надо образовывать. Люди используют эти механизмы в речи. Надо понять в чем разница.

Comment: Дело в том, что далеко не всегда это будет удачно. Если уверены в своей грамотности по части стилистики... Но вы в ней вообще не шарите (не пытаюсь обидеть, говорю, как есть).

Comment: Так стилистику определяет использование. Начните использовать и будет стилистика. Интереснее грамматика, она тупо запрещает использование и точка, против неё не попрешь, а против стилистики можно переть и определять её

Comment: Это да, хорошо сказано, но в большинстве случаев надо, чтобы изначально было удачно (красиво и грамотно).

Answer (score 3):

Имеется вот такой список: [*Русские слова с суффиксом -ишк*](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA).
Из него и выбираем слова мужского рода:

амбаришко, армячишко;
бурнусишко; [см. примечание]
возишко;
голосишко, городишко, граммофонишко;
дворишко, домишко;
журналишко;
заборишко, заводишко, зипунишко;
инструментишко;
кабачишко, капотишко, картузишко, кафтанишко, кнутишко, кулачишко...
умишко...

**Примечание.** Не знаю, правда, насколько верен и полон этот список.
Например, [*бурнусишко*](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE) обозначается как слово среднего рода, а цитата приводится с мужским родом (*Елизавета Николаевна показала на **свой худой бурнусишко, сшитый** из лёгонького летнего трико...*).

**Дополнение**
"Нашлись" еще:
бульваришко, лбишко, огородишко, ульишко;
народушко, сараюшко, хлебушко (суфф. *-ушк/-юшк*).

*...а с другой — еще опаснее, что задавит сам православный **народушко**, который волновался, как океан* (Н. Лесков. Несмертельный Голован).

*Легавые, что обложили с вечера этот дырявый **сараюшко**, очень даже крепко берегут нас для вашего же спокойствия* (А. Приставкин. Кукушата, или Жалобная песнь для успокоения сердца).

Comment: Правильно "народишко". https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/народишко

Comment: Неужели? В том же Викисловаре: 1.  https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC_-%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA. 2. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE. У Ефремовой: наро́душка и наро́душко м. разг. (https://lexicography.online/explanatory/efremova/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0). *...и черным-черно разливался по соборному двору народушко* (Булгаков).

Comment: Не подхожу к этому формально, у меня этот вариант не звучит, может, он немного устарел (старомодный). Лучше один вариант оставить, как сделали в БТС, а то разнобой.

Comment: В орфографическом словаре — "народишко". Два варианта орфографии — зло. Лингвисты это хорошо понимают.

Comment: @oleedd  "народишко" – уничижительное, а "народушко" – тёплое, ласковое, пусть и просторечное.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Ладно, принял. Мне казалось, что тот же смысл.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Спасибо за поддержку, Саша. На самом деле такая пара (-ишк/-ушк) не единственная. Вот, по-быстрому: амбар**и**шка — амбар**у**шка, бород**и**шка — бород**у**шка, дом**и**шка — дом**у**шка... А вот это вообще "двойная пара": сараишка, сараишко — сараюшка, сараюшко. Наверно, еще есть. Не буду искать — тут *глобальное* время требуется, а я его и так уже много потратила, отвечая тоже на *заданный вопрос*.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнительный ответ**

Мне кажется, что *полный* список слов мужского рода на *-о* составить невозможно, потому что словообразование с использованием суффиксов, придающих словам уменьшительно-ласкательное или уничижительное значение, происходит постоянно, но не все *новообразования* попадают в словари, что естественно.

В качестве примера: [Род слова «сундучишечко»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473384/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE/473392#473392) (домишечко, умишечко).

Еще:
*Рваные лапти, худой **армячишечко**,

Страх в опустевших глазах.*
Ю. Береснев. Из ненаписанного Некрасовым

И еще, навскидку — что вокруг и чего нет в словарях:

*...даже самый непоседливый опер обязательно подыщет себе какой-никакой **стульчишко** поудобнее* (Л. Пучков. Тактика выжженной земли);
*Гость положил руку на его плечо, принуждая сесть на куцый **табуретишко*** (Е. Арсеньева. Гарем Ивана Грозного);
*На одной стороне сцены дрянной письменный столишко с некрашеным деревянным стулом перед ним, а на другой — оборванный **диванишко*** (А. Писемский. Русские лгуны (**1865**));
*Этот рыжий, в царапках **шкафишко** вмиг провалился сквозь землю вместе с рваными, зачитанными книжонками* (В. Смирнов. Весной Семнадцатого (**1968**)).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147173/discussion-on-answer-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Заданный вопрос: ***Почему эти слова изменили свои окончания, ведь это не логично?***

1. Большинство существительных мужского рода на А, относящихся к первому склонению, являются **одушевленными**, но эта группа также немногочисленная. Поэтому окончания первого склонения отчасти выражают **женский род** существительных.
2. Категория **одушевленности/неодушевленности** для существительных мужского рода  связана с именительным, родительным и винительным падежами.
3. В **первом  склонении** без особого конфликта друг с другом присутствуют существительные **женского** рода и **одушевленные** существительные **мужского** рода: *юноша/юноши/юношу, вельможа/вельможи/вельможу*. А также туда вписались сущ. с **суффиксом ИШК**: *мальчишка/мальчишки/мальчишку, купчишка /купчишки/купчишку и др.*
4. А вот **неодушевленным** существительным *заборишка/заборишки/заборишку*, *домишка/домишки/домишку* и т.д. там было не очень уютно. Чувствовали  они себя **чужаками** в этом «женском» склонении, вот и перебрались **во второе склонение,** к своим поближе: *домишко/домишка/домишко, заборишко/заборишка/заборишко.*

Те же формы существительных, которые остались в первом склонении, считаются  **разговорными**.

5. Только несколько примеров… :(

Не очень-то верилось, чтобы кукуйские немцы избили этого **купчишку** (1930).

Намеднись наехали на наш Бугуруслан сто калмыков со своим старшиной, Фомою Алексеевым, разграбили все обывательские домы, и мой **домишка** претерпел  (1939-1945).

Пожалуй, поклонись господину моему генералу и побей челом, чтоб пожаловал, не покинул маво **домишку** (1930).